# Webpack multiple entry and multiple build files

Tags: webpack

I have a react project with folder structure as

- parentDir
  -->Dir1
  -->Dir2
  -->Dir3
  -->Dir4

I want my build files in features directory which is under parentDir with structure as

- features
  -->Dir1Bundle
  -->Dir2Bundle
  -->Dir3Bundle
  -->Dir4Bundle

My webpack.config.js file is

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = [{
  output: {
    path: __dirname + './features/bulletinBoard',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  entry: './Bulletin_Board/index.js',
}, {
  output: {
    path: __dirname + './features/communityDirectory',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  entry: './Community_Directory/index.js',
}];

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'Bulletin_Board'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=500000' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=500000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.eot/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject' },
      { test: /\.woff2/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
      { test: /\.woff/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/font-ttf' }
    ]
  }
};
```

According to me everything is fine but I'm getting error as

```
webpack 1.15.0
Usage: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html

Options:
  --help, -h, -?
  --config
  --context
  --entry
  --module-bind
  --module-bind-post
  --module-bind-pre
  --output-path
  --output-file
  --output-chunk-file
  --output-named-chunk-file
  --output-source-map-file
  --output-public-path
  --output-jsonp-function
  --output-pathinfo
  --output-library
  --output-library-target
  --records-input-path
  --records-output-path
  --records-path
  --define
  --target
  --cache                                                                                           [default:
  --watch, -w
  --watch which closes when stdin ends
  --watch-aggregate-timeout
  --watch-poll
  --hot
  --debug
  --devtool
  --progress
  --resolve-alias
  --resolve-loader-alias
  --optimize-max-chunks
  --optimize-min-chunk-size
  --optimize-minimize
  --optimize-occurence-order
  --optimize-dedupe
  --prefetch
  --provide
  --labeled-modules
  --plugin
  --bail
  --profile
  -d                                    shortcut for --debug --devtool sourcemap --output-pathinfo
  -p                                    shortcut for --optimize-minimize
  --json, -j
  --colors, -c
  --sort-modules-by
  --sort-chunks-by
  --sort-assets-by
  --hide-modules
  --display-exclude
  --display-modules
  --display-chunks
  --display-error-details
  --display-origins
  --display-cached
  --display-cached-assets
  --display-reasons, --verbose, -v

Output filename not configured.
```

I don't know what i'm missing in this and my file name is also correct. My `webpack.config.js` is under parentDir.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of error in your configuration file

You need export a configuration object not a array

```
module.exports = [{
  // wrong
  ...
}]

module.exports = {
  //right
  ...
}
```

and you are overwriting previous value of `module.exports` when you are adding `rules` for loaders
insted of

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
    ...
    ]
  }
}
```

do

```
module.exports.module = rules: [
...
]
```

this will add a new property instead of overwriting the existing

and use correct configuration pattern like this to define multiple entry point
and use copy-webpack-plugin to copy yor file in different places

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './Bulletin_Board/index.js',
    './second_entry_file.js' 
  ],

  output: {
    path: __dirname + './features/communityDirectory',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.[name].js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'Bulletin_Board'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'},
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=500000' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=500000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      { test: /\.eot/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject' },
      { test: /\.woff2/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/font-woff2' },
      { test: /\.woff/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=300000&mimetype=application/font-ttf' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I want output also in different folder  "path: __dirname + './features/[name]' " . Is the will give output in different folders

Comment: no this will not give output in different folder but there are webpack plugin witch will copy your file in different folders after compilation

Comment: take a look at this plugin https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin